# Add content to the same column with a condition - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a trouble with this. 
I have a table:

Table test1

```
Id_keyword Id_product
2          1280
2          1281
3          1280
4          3478
4          3912
5          1280
etc.
```

Table test2

```
ID_product      Tag
1
2
3
4
...
1280            2,3,5
1281            2
etc.
```

I need to add to the column Tag from table test1 Id_keyword like this - 2,3,5

I tryed something like this but don´t know how to make the condition - if it find the product_id it will add to the column Tag the keyword_id with comma and if it find the same product_id it will add to the content:

```
UPDATE test2 SET Tag=(SELECT id_keyword FROM test1 WHERE test1.Id_product=test2.ID_product)
```

Could somebody help me with that? 
I can´t find any solution.

Comment: Use `group_concat( id_keyword )` with `group by Id_product`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just a simple update join;

```
UPDATE test2
JOIN (
  SELECT id_product, GROUP_CONCAT(id_keyword ORDER BY id_keyword) tag
  FROM test1 GROUP BY id_product) z
  ON z.id_product = test2.id_product
SET test2.tag = z.tag
```

This joins test2 with a query that concatenates all id_keywords pr id_product into a temporary field called tag, and assigns that tag value to test2.tag.

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff8a5/1).

As @strawberry points out in the comments, storing the data comma separated in a table to later query it as separate items is *not* a good idea since the database will no longer be able to optimize the queries in any way. If that's what you're attempting, it's better to keep the data stored normalized just as it is already stored.

Comment: Feels like a step backwards to me.

Comment: @Strawberry Denormalizing joins may not be a good idea for transaction intensive data (and by may not be I mean I agree that it isn't), however there are legitimate uses for - for example - reporting. I can't tell which case this is, but I'll make the distinction more clear in the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I need an update of this code. I put inside column lang.

```
CREATE TABLE test1
    (`Id_keyword` int, `lang` int, `Id_product` int)
;

INSERT INTO test1
    (`Id_keyword`,`lang`, `Id_product`)
VALUES
    (2,4, 1280),
    (2,4, 1281),
    (3,4, 1280),
    (4,4, 3478),
    (4,4, 3912),
    (5,4, 1280)
;

CREATE TABLE test2
    (`ID_product` int, `lang` int,  `Tag` varchar(32))
;

INSERT INTO test2
    (`ID_product`,`lang`, `Tag`)
VALUES
    (1280,4, NULL),
    (1281,3, NULL)
;

UPDATE test2
JOIN (
  SELECT id_product, GROUP_CONCAT(id_keyword ORDER BY id_keyword) tag
  FROM test1 GROUP BY id_product) z
  ON z.id_product = test2.id_product
SET test2.tag = z.tag
```

I need to put there one condition:
WHERE test1.lang=test2.lang

but have no idea how to put inside.

Thank you for any help.